# SQL Query to Select But Skip Certain Rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "MYTABLE" that looks like this:

```
ID   | TIMESTAMP  | DATA
1    | 150233939  | xxx
2    | 150233940  | xxx
3    | 150233941  | xxx
4    | 150233942  | xxx
5    | 150233943  | xxx
6    | 150233944  | xxx
7    | 150233945  | xxx
8    | 150233946  | xxx
9    | 150233947  | xxx
```

I can easily get all of the items using:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
```

But this table is going to get massive and it contains data points that will be shown on a graph. So instead of getting ALL of the data points, I want them spaced out. For example, I want a query that would return

```
1,3,5,7,9
```

Or:

```
1,4,8,9
```

Is there a way to do this on the query level?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the data like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where mod(id,5) = 0
```

This divides the data quite nicely, but it is SUPER SLOW. Is there another way to make it faster?

Comment: Add according WHERE - `WHERE id IN (1,3,5,7,9)`, for example.

Comment: Is the sequence guaranteed to be continuous (no breaks)? If so, see MOD() (and UNION) you want the modulus results unioned with first and last results.

Comment: I have a huge set of datapoints. One every second. I am trying to get data once every minute, or once every 5 minutes so that the graph doesnt take a year to load.